# Convert Datetime in sql

Tags: sql

I Want To Convert The Datetime From **20-feb-16:00:00** To Something Like Like **fri 20-feb-2017**. I Tried This Code But It Just Displays Operation Concluded

```
Select Datetime
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113) AS NEWDATE
FROM TWEETS;
```

Comment: Do you normally speak in ALL CAPS?

Comment: @GordonLinoff That was rude.

Comment: sorry,did not notice that as I was eating while typing. I did not realise its considered rude

Comment: What RDBMS and version?

Comment: @MartinSmith its a proprietary one by Dr Timothy Cribbin from Brunel University. It had no info along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this post from Microsoft about formatting date and time:

[Date Time Formatting for Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187819.aspx)

and then adapt your function to meet exactly your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of RDBMS and its version. you can use both CONVERT or FROMAT depending on the context. take a look at [THIS](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) and you'll find the right answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server: Using a combination of [**`datename()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) and [**`convert()`** styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
select left(datename(weekday,getdate()),3)
    +' '+replace(convert(varchar(24),getdate(),106),' ','-')
```

returns: `Sat 11-Mar-2017`

---

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
select format(getdate(),'ddd dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

returns: `Sat 11-Mar-2017`

But `format()` can be slower, take a look here: [`format()` is nice and all, but… - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)